# In R programming, what is the difference between the any and | (or) Boolean operator?

Tags: r, booleanquery

- `(cond1 | cond2 | cond3 | ...)` means *"is one or more of a bunch of conditions true?"*
- `any(cond1, cond2, cond3 ....)` means *"are any of the conditions true?"*

As such aren't we saying the same thing here?

Are there any advantages of using one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`|` is vectorized--it returns a result with the same length as the longest input and will recycle if needed.

`any` looks at all the inputs and returns result of length 1.

`||` make only a single comparison, using the first elements of its inputs regardless of their length, and returns a result of length 1.

```
x = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
y = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)

any(x, y)
# [1] TRUE
## There's a TRUE in there somewhere

x | y
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
## Only the 2nd index of the vectors contains a TRUE

x || y
# [1] FALSE
## The first position of the vectors does not contain a TRUE.
```

If the inputs are all of length one, then `x1 | x2 | x3` is equivalent to `x1 || x2 || x3` is equivalent to `any(x1, x2, x3)`. Otherwise, no guarantee.